# How to remove watchers created by angular directives after $compile

Tags: angularjs

I have been facing some performance issues when opening modals multiple times in angular, and I have found out that every time the dialog service is asked to create a new modal, the watcher count in the scope increases dramatically.

The DialogService is as follows:

```
.factory("DialogService", function($q, $compile){
        return {
            toast:function(text){
                Dialog.toast(text);
            },
            alert:function(text){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var d = Dialog.alert(text);
                d.bind("hide", function(){
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            showModal:function(options){
                var dialog = new Dialog(options);
                dialog.show(function(){
                    var self = this;
                    if ( "scope" in options ) $compile(self.contentLayer)(options.scope);

                    options.scope.dismiss = function(){
                        dialog.hide();
                    }   
                });
                if ( "hide" in options ){
                    dialog.bind("hide", options.hide);
                }
            },...
```

The problem I´m facing is that every time a new modal is created, it polutes the scope with new watchers when I use directives.

I fixed most of the problem by adding observers that remove watchers when the node is destroyed in my custom directives, but ng-repeat, ng-if, etc... inside the modal content keep adding watchers every time showModal is called.

Now, I´m not even sure what approach should I try.

Now I´m trying to remove watchers created with the dialog, but I didn´t succeed, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What happens if you create a fake scope object and pass that to options (if your dialog needs properties present on scope)? Or if you simply don't pass in a scope object?

Comment: angular will automatically remove watchers registered with to the scope when the scope is destroyed. Are you reusing the same scope over and over for each modal and/or manually adding and removing DOM elements?

Comment: tge watchers added by built-in directives will removed by angular along with the scopes, when garbage collector destroys the scope objects

Comment: Nope,  the scope is passed to the dialog,  but the scope remains.  It.s the same until the view is changed.  And the dialogservice creates a new node and remove it on dismiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me some time, but finally I was able to achieve the desired behaviour

First, instead of passing directly the scope to the dialog service as shown in the question, it´s better to create a child scope from the scope passed in options.

This way, every time $compile is called to build a modal it won´t pollute the parent scope with watches and other stuff and it´s easy to destroy the newly created scope when the modal is closed.

The resulting code for the service would look like this:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .factory("DialogService", function($q, $compile){
        return {
            toast:function(text){
                Dialog.toast(text);
            },
            alert:function(text){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var d = Dialog.alert(text);
                d.bind("hide", function(){
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            showModal:function(options){
                var childScope;
                var dialog = new Dialog(options);
                dialog.show(function(){
                    var self = this;    
                    if ( "scope" in options ){
                        var childScope = options.scope.$new();
                        $compile(self.contentLayer)(childScope);

                        options.scope.dismiss = function(){ 
                            dialog.hide();
                        }

                        dialog.bind("hide", function(){
                            childScope.$destroy();
                        });
                    }   
                });
                if ( "hide" in options ){
                    dialog.bind("hide", options.hide);
                }   
            },
            confirm:function(text){
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                Dialog.confirm(text, function(){
                    deferred.resolve();
                }, function(){
                    deferred.reject();
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    })
;
```

**Extra**

At this point, I thought I solved the issue, but through console logs I could see that digest cycles where still running more and more every time I opened a new dialog, although the watches remained constant this time.

What was happening is that I have a lot of custom directives; I´m very careful about adding the following lines at the end of every directive´s link function to avoid performance issues in scenarios like the one described above:

```
var watchers = [
     $scope.$watch(...),
     $scope.$watch(...),
     ...
];
...
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (!document.body.contains($element[0])){
        observer.disconnect();
        dropdown.remove();
        for ( var i = 0; i < watchers.length; i++ ){
            watchers[i]();
        }
        $scope.$destroy();
        return;
    }
});  
var config = { childList: true, subtree: false  /*attributes: true, characterData: true*/ };
observer.observe(document.querySelector('body'), config);
```

Looks fine, right? well... works most of the times, but when I have something like this inside a directive (and that was the case):

```
var clickHandler = function(event){
    var isChild = $($element).has(event.target).length > 0 || $(dropdown).has(event.target).length > 0;
    var isSelf = $element[0] == event.target || dropdown == event.target;

    $scope.$apply(function(){
        if (!isChild && !isSelf) {
            $scope.mdSelectCtrl.dismiss();
        }
    }); 
}

$document.bind('click', clickHandler);
```

It was adding the click event on every $compile, the click event causes another digest cycle (even if the scope has been destroyed, at this point didn´t want to dig deeper); taking into account that I could easily use the same directive 10-15 times in the modal content, that meant that every call to $compile caused that on every click a lot of digest cycles where run, killing performance.

The solution to this is simple: remove DOM event listeners when the scope of a directive is destroyed:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if (!document.body.contains($element[0])){
        observer.disconnect();
        dropdown.remove();
        for ( var i = 0; i < watchers.length; i++ ){
            watchers[i]();
        }
        $scope.$destroy();
        $document.unbind('click', clickHandler);
        return;
    }
});
```

**Note**

After changing the dialog service, I realize that maybe MutationObserver are not needed to track if the node still exists, and I could use instead:

```
$scope.$on("destroy")
```

But I don´t feel like changing any more code for today to test it.